# A particle moving on the plane with rotation and translation

Tags: coordinate-systems

> A particle is located on the coordinate plane at $(5,0)$. Each move for the particle consists of a counter-clockwise rotation of $45^{\circ}$ about the origin followed by a translation of $10$ units in the positive x-direction. If the position of the particle after $150$ moves is $(p,q)$, find $|p|+|q|$

---

I was discussing this problem with one of my classmate, and he said that, let the initial position $z_0= 5$ then the position after n movements would be $$z_n=[z_{n-1} × e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}]+10$$ My question is, is this correct? If it is correct, then how did he derive it?

Comment: It is correct but not the final solution. Presumably they want $z_n$ as a function of $z_0$ and not of the preceeding position $z_{n-1}$ which for the time being is as unknown to us as $z_n\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. But how is ut correct? I mean how do we derive the relation for $z_n$?

Comment: When you represent the position of the particle as complex number $z=x+iy$ what does a multiplication of $z$ do with $e^{i\phi}$ ?

Comment: @KurtG. It rotates it by angle $\phi$ right?

Comment: Right. Does this explain the formula that maps $z_{n-1}$ to $z_n$ ?

Comment: @KurtG. So rotating and adding a 10 gives us the next position. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. The formula does exactly that. The really interesting task is to find out the exact position of $z_n$ without recourse to $z_{n-1}\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. For that we need to find a charteristic equation of the recursion right?

Comment: This can be a way of doing it. Let's end the discussion now. Task is clear. Try your best.